# write() function not overwriting

Tags: python

I'm trying to overwrite the content of a file. However, instead of overwriting, the program  appends the characters at the end of the line. The file contains the number 0. This is the code i'm using:

```
file = open('my_file', 'w')

for x in range(5):
>>file.write(str(x))
```

The result I'm getting is '01234', but I was expecting '4'.

Comment: That's.... what `file.write()` is supposed to do. To overwrite, you'd have to repeatedly open and close the file. However, I'd just suggest counting and writing when you finish the work.

Answer (score 3):

This is perfectly normal. Opening the file in `w` mode truncates the file *once*, immediately after opening it. It does not reset the file pointer after each write. The writes occur serially, with each write leaving the file pointer at the *end* of the data written.

To get the desired result, you need to re-open the file in each iteration of the loop.

```
for x in range(5):
    with open('my_file', 'w') as f:
        f.write(str(x))
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be more inefficient than just incrementing `x` and writing when you're done?

Comment: @OrdoFlammae - OP wasn't asking about efficiency.

Comment: No, you're right, he wasn't. However, I just thought it would be good to mention that it's really inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason you are getting “01234” is because you put the code in a for loop: x increases from 0 to 4 and is written to the text file every single time. Try removing the for loop and setting x equal to 4.

You can also try using an open function in write mode inside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are opening a file outside of for loop and and same file is opened for further operations. You are not closing the file. So even if it is in write mode pointer is not getting reset.

Here is sample code:

```
for x in range(5):
    f = open('1.txt' , 'w')
    f.write(str(x))
    f.close()
```